# SPpagebuilder accordion +Fetch as Google problem

Tags: jquery, seo, google

Recently i purchase theme based on SP PageBuiler and description says it is included as Pro version. But SPpagebuilder forums required their subscription witch i of course don't have... And theme dev refuses to help me.

And actual problem is that i have accordion components on page, and Google sees them like user, only first one open. Is there a way to trick google engine to see whole page content?

I have some prices categorised in that accordions and of course it is looking way better collapsed, but seems like Google is blocking that solution. I want to use google highlighter tool and it cant do that also...

Is there a way around it?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: A link to the live website might help if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what is your problem - I guess you are concerned that Google can't see content that is "hidden" inside the accordion with the first eye.
Note that content that is "animated hidden" with javascript inside sliders, tabs, accordions etc is usually accessible and available in the page. This can be the case even if it's ajax loaded content that is getting loaded with the click of a button-link, as Google can follow links.

However, there can be cases that this content won't be accessible and available in the document, so Google crawler won't see it.

Some reasons for this is that content Google is restricted from reading javascript and other assets files that make the whole html page looks and behaves the way it does. Also if certain text/content is generated by javascript that Google isn't allowed to crawl then Google won't know what content your js code will produce to your page.

You have to find out what is your case here. Start by reviewing via Google Webmasters Tools for what Google Crawler can see in your page and if there are assets that are restricted to access (usually via the robots.txt)

Another thing you can do to see if the additional content that you are concerned about exists in your html, is to disable javascript and stylesheets on your browser and see only the html output - or check the source code of your page. Search if you can see the content in question inside your html. If you can see it there, then likely Google should be able to see it as well.